# How to port-foward an external device plugged into an ethernet adaptor to another ethernet adaptor?

Tags: windows-10, port-forwarding

I have a camera device working as a webserver with a local IP/Port **192.168.0.250:80** over *HTTP* protocol, which is connected to one ethernet adaptor of the PC having the IP **192.168.0.1** and Gateway **10.20.30.10** and I wanted to access this camera remotelly throught another ethernet adaptor from the LAN where this PC is connected with IP **10.20.30.40** and gateway **10.20.30.10**.

I wanted to access this camera remotelly, mapped as **http://10.20.30.40:8008**.

I already access this camera in local network as **http://192.168.0.250:80**.

According to the following diagram, I have tryed some options:

[image: Schematic]

The first attempt was by mapping the camera connected to the 1st ethernet adaptor directly to the 2nd ethernet adaptor connected to the external network:

```
REM Route from Camera to Remote
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=192.168.0.250 listenport=80 connectaddress=10.20.30.40 connectport=8008
```

However, seemed too simple, and not surprisingly didn't work.

What am I'm missing here?

*Side note:*
*Most Portfowarding tutorials explains how to map from localhost, not from external devices.*

**[EDIT1]**

It is not intended to foward streamming video, instead, just to take sparse snapshots upon request, via URL sentences.

**[EDIT2]**

Updated picture enphasizing the Http protocol.

Comment: Is that camera access supposed to be happening over TCP or over UDP? Portproxy is TCP-only, while e.g. video streams via RTSP require UDP.

Comment: Hi, once this camera hosts an webserver and we wanted to make access to a 'webpage' through browser it actually works over the HTTP protocol, sorry if I didn't make it clear, I'll try edit the question. And, indeed, it is not required to stream video remotelly, just take snapshots upon request via URL sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct command that worked:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=10.20.30.40 listenport=8008 connectaddress=192.168.0.250 connectport=80
```

BTW, I had mislead in all the original attempts what should be configured as **listener** and what should be configured to **connect** ( just done a bare swap on them, from the first attempt ). I got the tip [here](https://www.edaboard.com/threads/how-to-port-foward-an-external-device-plugged-into-an-ethernet-adaptor-to-another-ethernet-adaptor.402791/#post-1735198).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sure, I could do that, but doing this I would redirect to a link on which I asked the same question and someone there (an experienced member) replied with this simple answer (https://www.edaboard.com/threads/how-to-port-foward-an-external-device-plugged-into-an-ethernet-adaptor-to-another-ethernet-adaptor.402791/#post-1735198); anyway, I thought the above "BTW" should suffice. Anyway, I will search for more details elsewhere and improve the answer as you said.